# How can I call/refer to another property in the same models in django

Tags: python, django, properties, model

I am creating a web app for creating a proposal/quotation for machines or equipment. I have a models for `QuotationItem` which has these properties:

In my models.py:

```
class QuotationItem(models.Model):
    product = models.Charfield(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    line_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tagging = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now, I want the 2 properties (line_number and tagging) be connected. Example:

```
line_number = 1,
tagging = "Equipment - 1"

line_number = 2,
tagging = "Equipment - 2"
```

In short, I want to set the `tagging` property with a default value of `f"Equipment - {line_number}"`

I am expecting that part of the `request.data` is the `line_number`, and therefore, I want the `tagging` to have that above default value, if none was provided. Is there a way to do this in models? Or should I handle this in views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value as used in the field definition (even when you use a callable) has no access to the instance. You would have to override `save` or connect to the `pre_save` signal:

```
class QuotationItem(models.Model):
    # ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:  # initial creation
            self.tagging = f"Equipment - {self.line_number}"
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl. What I actually wanted is to set the `self.tagging` to `f"Equipment - {self.line_number}"` if none was provided in the `request.data`. I did minor modifications from your code and it worked:

`if not self.pk and not self.tagging:`

Also, I added `null=True` to tagging since it is not accepting no value upon creation (although it is really supposedly be `null=False`)